# best way to edit CSS and get the changes back to SASS

Tags: css, sass

I find very convenient to edit a CSS from Chrome, and then saving my edits directly. 
But then I need a way to take this changes back to SASS by hand, and I think that may be there is a tool to do this more easily.

I understand that it is difficult to have a tool that automatically does that, but may be there is some tool that can at least do a comparison between the SASS file and the CSS file (like a diff) and let me see the SASS in the right pane and the CSS in the left pane, in a synchronized view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sass Sleuth](http://mobify.github.io/sass-sleuth/) is a tool that will solve this problem for you.

Alternatively you could use [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/) for Firefox, or [Sass Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sass-inspector/lkofmbmllpgfbnonmnenkiakimpgoamn/details) for Chrome.

Comment: Looks nice. I will be using it. Thanks

Comment: Hello from 2016! All 3 of these links are broken. Dang :\

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this nifty online service which does just that: https://css2sass.heroku.com/ or the code: https://github.com/jpablobr/css2sass

Comment: That is not exactly what I wanted, but it's convenient and I didn't know it

Comment: I accept the other answer, because it is more what I wanted. But I think that this answer, even a little off-topic, is useful. It received a down-vote, but I disagree